# Adobe analytics web beacon response 204?

Tags: adobe-analytics, web-analytics, beacon

For Adobe Analytics tracking HTTP response header (sorry I can't paste my request here for privacy), I can see the following

```
Content-Length:43
Content-Type:image/gif
```

I am not sure why Adobe Analytics returns 43 size tracking pixel rather than smaller one. Does Adobe Analytics client-side javascript need to read this Content-Length header for any verification?

What if I return HTTP 204 no content, will that also work?

Comment: that's the size of the raw (encoded) data, not the size of the pixel itself. it's really a 2x2 pixel. And unless you are on some ancient browser, it doesn't actually get output to the page.

Comment: @CrayonViolent still, it could be smaller than 43 bytes. I don't understand 1. why it is 2x2 or 43 bytes rather than something smaller. 2. why the response not just returning 204 because I guess it is not going to use the 2x2 pixel?

Answer (score 0):

the pixel is really only there because of legacy systems and old browser support. 
experience cloud & moving to AAM will change the response to a javascript JSON object

43 bytes is pretty tiny, I wouldn't worry about 43 bytes. 2x2 pixel dimension really means nothing.

a `204` response is normal, unless you have AAM